# Annotation Attribute not accepting my variable

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

Iv'e read a lot on this now, and I have found examples of how with the newer ADT's switch statements have to be given constant expressions, but nothing is every mentioned about @Inject.

Here is an example of my problematic code.

```
 import roboguice.inject.InjectView;
 public abstract class YpListActivity extends GuiceListActivity 

     @InjectView(R.id.btnSearch)
     Button btnSearch;
     @InjectView(R.id.btnSpeech)
     View btnSpeech;
     @InjectView(R.id.etWhat)
     EditText etWhat;
     @InjectView(R.id.etWhere)
     EditText etWhere;
     @InjectView(R.id.tvIn)
     TextView tvIn;
     @InjectView(R.id.tvLocation)
     TextView tvLocation;
     @InjectView(R.id.tvCustom)
     private ToggleButton tvCustom;
     @InjectView(R.id.infoButton)
     private ImageView iconButton;
```

Every time I try and use something like @injectView(R.id.*), eclipse throws the error:

"The value for annotation attribute InjectView.value must be a constant expression."

I even tried changing it to this:

```
     private static final int btnsrch = new Integer(R.id.btnSearch);

     @InjectView(btnsrch )
     TableRow btnSearch ;
```

How is "btnsrch" not a constant expression??

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Change Java semantics, I guess.

Comment: See [RoboGuice bug # 139](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=139) for more info. [Library project IDs are not final as of ADT 14+](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields).

Answer (score 0):

Remove "private" and it should be working properly.